# Forward SNMP trap to different port

Tags: iptables, snmp

We have a system that receives traps from various devices.
Since the system does not run (and cannot run) as `root`, it listens to a non-default port (in our case 2162 instead of 162).
The problem is that some of the devices we manage, send their traps always to the default 162 port.

We therefore need to forward the traps, incoming on port 162, to port 2162.
I've tried the following but it does not work (it doesn't forward anything):

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2162`
`iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 2162 -j ACCEPT`

I'm a software engineer and not a system administrator and know very few about iptables, networking, NAT, etc.
I got the above statements googling a little.

Since the sender of the UDP packet is very important, we cannot simply create a small process, running as root, that receives traps on port 162 and creates new ones sending them to port 2162.
It would change the sending address.

The output of `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` is:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 11339 packets, 2709K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 to::2162
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 to:163.162.154.208:2162
    0     0 REDIRECT   udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 redir ports 2162
    0     0 REDIRECT   udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 redir ports 2162
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 to:163.162.154.208:2162
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 to::2162
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 to::2162

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 80991 packets, 5033K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    5   470 SNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            163.162.154.208     udp dpt:2162 to:163.162.154.208

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 80993 packets, 5033K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

While the output of `iptables -L -n -v` is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3372K packets, 561M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            163.162.154.208     udp dpt:2163
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            163.162.154.208     udp dpt:2162
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:2162
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            163.162.154.208     udp dpt:2162 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3349K packets, 733M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

The output of `netstat -lnup | grep 2162` is:

```
udp        0      0 :::2162                     :::*                                    13871/java
```

Comment: Please, post the output of `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` and `iptables -L -n -v`. Receiving packets on the machine itself you should look at `INPUT` chain not `FORWARD`.

Comment: I edited the question including the output of the suggested commands.

Comment: Please, post also the output of `netstat -lnup | grep 2162`.

Comment: Edited the question including also the output of the netstat command.

Comment: Are you using `iptables` to redirect IPv4 traffic to IPv6 socket? The notation `:::2162` is used for IPv6 listening socket on port 2162.

Comment: The process that receives the SNMP traps, simply opens a DatagramSocket, listening on port 2162 for packets coming from any host. We don't specify the type of address. When using the snmptrap utility from the net-snmp package, sending the trap to port 2162 on localhost, the listener receives it normally and sees 127.0.0.1 as the sender.